An html page knows what was entered in controlname, only after a change in the fields
I made a form with FormsModule, the form has an object with 7 fields, which are expressed in html as selected tags,
the form in html manages to maintain reciprocity with the typescript, but at first, when I display the 7 fields, it does not show me what is already in the object even though I Register it in the new contrloname()
the code in the component:
    this.scheduleForm = new FormGroup({
      Sunday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[0]),
      Monday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[1]),
      Tuesday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[2]),
      Wednesday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[3]),
      Thursday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[4]),
      Friday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[5]),
      Saturday: new FormControl(this.schedule?.daysByid[6]),
    });

in the html:
    <form action="" [formGroup]="scheduleForm">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let i of daysOfWeek">{{this.getById(scheduleForm.controls[i].value)?.name}}</th>//As long as I do not select an option, it is not shown to me and the fields are set to null, but if I select it proceeds as usual and is saved.
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeek;index as i">
                        <select name="day" id="day" [formControlName]="day">
                            <option *ngFor="let v of this.byDays(i)">{{v.id}} </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <ng-template #empty>
                    <td> </td>
                </ng-template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" (click)="saveSchedule()">Save Schedule</button>

    </form>

